# Parent/master project in git

Tags: git

I have a project "A" that is a Git repository. I would like to be able to make multiple copies of project A (B and C), and modify them for clients.

"A" is the master so sometimes when I do new functionality i would like to be able to pull them into B or C. But some commits should just stay in A and only be used if making a new clone.

How do I do that with Git? That is:

- how to copy A? (Clone?)
- how to get specific commits into B and C?

Please keep in mind that this all happening locally - not on GitHub. I use OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - how to copy A?

`git clone` is the way, meaning you establish a *publication* link between A and B,C, allowing for pushing/pulling commits between them.

> - how to get specific commits into B and C?

By having in the repo A:

- private branches where you develop as many feature you want (but this branch is never pushed anywhere else)
- public branch which will be pushed to B and C
- merge or [`rebase --onto`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994463/how-to-cherry-pick-a-range-of-commits-and-merge-into-another-branch/1994491#1994491) your commits from your private branch on top of your public branch, then push that public branch to B or C.

---

One workflow would be for instance:

```
cd ~/projectA
git checkout master
git branch private
# do some commits, some private, some useful to a
git checkout master
git branch feature_for_a
git cherry-pick sha1_from_private

cd ~/project_B
git fetch project_A
git checkout --track feature_for_a # check modifs for a
git checkout master
git merge feature_for_a
# do some client specific modifications
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Can you write the commands for a typical workflow? Eg.

  1. git clone ~/project_a ~/project_b
  2. [make changes to project_a]
  3. [now what? :)]

Comment: @jriff: answer updated with *one example* of possible workflow

Comment: BTW. Some commits should only go to some of the clones. A commit might be a feature or a bugfix that doesn't need to go to all the clones. Also I think it would be better to pull the commits I want rather than push them from project_a.

Comment: @jriff: the cherry-pick step is meant precisely to pick and choose what commit you want in branches meant for other repo. And since you fetch them (and create a local branch in b for tracking what you have fetch, that is similar to pull them), you are not pushing anything from project_a: you can't, project_b being a non-bare repo, it is not eligible to any direct push from project_a

Comment: Thanks a lot - could you have a look at the answer I made - it is similar to your workflow - only a little simpler - can you explain the drawbacks of that approach?

Comment: @jriff: I believe I just did ;)

Comment: Our comments crossed each other :^)